# loop in xml and delete some values

Tags: c#, xml, loops, xmlnode

Please help

I want too loop through all the below xml

and delete the "Att1" and Att2"

leaving all the others untouched

here is the example xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main>
    <example Att1="" Att2="" Att3="" Att4="" Att5="">
        <name>value</name>
        <name1>value</name1>
        <name2>value</name2>
        <name3>value</name3>
    </example>

    <example1 Att1="" Att2="" Att3="" Att4="" Att5="">
        <name>value</name>
        <name1>value</name1>
        <name2>value</name2>
        <name3>value</name3>
    </example1>

    <example2 Att1="" Att2="" Att3="" Att4="" Att5="">
        <name>value</name>
        <name1>value</name1>
        <name2>value</name2>
        <name3>value</name3>
    </example2>
</main>
```

sorry indeed I was wrong , unfortunately I can't post the original one

Comment: Post a real xml. A tag can not have two attributes with the same name (`<example Att1="" Att2="" Att2="" Att3="" Att3="">`). then post what you have tried so far so that we can fix it.

Comment: You should look up Linq-To-Xml, or fiddle around with it by including `System.Linq.Xml` and instantiating an XDocument. It's fairly easy.

Comment: hi , yes L.B I was wrong about the XML ( changed it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename); //XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);

xDoc.Descendants()
    .SelectMany(d => d.Attributes())
    .Where(a => a.Name == "Att1" || a.Name == "Att2")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Remove());

var newXml = xDoc.ToString(); //xDoc.Save(filename);
```

Comment: it works GREAT !!! Thanks !!! do you have an idea how can I add too loop the attributes I want eventually dynamically add values that I want to remove. I was thinking about adding text boxes or with a loop show the attributes and some how to select the one that I need , THANKS IN ADVANCE !!